# How to get the current time with GHCJS?

Tags: ghcjs

How to get the current time with GHCJS? Should i try to access `Date` or use Haskell base libraries? Is there an utility function somewhere in the GHCJS base libraries?

Comment: The haskell libraries seem to work - any reason not to use them?

Comment: I think that i did not find a way to use them. Would you write an answer here about your idea? I will try it and mark it as the correct answer if it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Data.Time.Clock` module seems to work well:

```
import Data.Time.Clock (getCurrentTime)
import Data.Time.Format -- Show instance
main = do
  now <- getCurrentTime
  print now
```

Comment: Yes, this works, and it is way cleaner, thanks! This introduces a dependency on `time`

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found currently is quite ugly, but it works for me, so maybe it can save some time to somebody:

```
{-# LANGUAGE JavaScriptFFI #-}

import GHCJS.Types( JSVal )
import GHCJS.Prim( fromJSString )

foreign import javascript unsafe "Date.now()+''" dateNow :: IO (JSVal)

asInteger = read (fromJSString dateNow) :: Integer -- this happens in IO
```

The ugliness comes from not finding a `JSInteger` type in GHCJS, which would be needed in order to get the result of `Date.now()` which is a long integer. So i need to produce a string concatenating a string to the result of `Date.now()` in Javascript. At this point i could get a `JSString` as result, but that would not be an instance of `Read` so using `read` would not work. So i get a `JSValue` and convert it to `String` using `fromJSString`.

Eventually there might be a `JSInteger` in GHCJS, or `JSString` might become an instance of `Read`, so if you are reading this from the future try out something more elegant!